# //The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I updated cloud firestore dependency in my project, but old code occur.

The error:

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.?

model.dart

```
Product.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
  _featured = snapshot.data()[FEATURED];//error occurs here
  _brand = snapshot.data()[BRAND];//error occurs here
  _category = snapshot.data()[CATEGORY];//error occurs here
}
```

update.dart

```
 FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.
            collection("items").where("shortInfo",whereIn: snapshots.
            data.docs[index].data()[EcommerceApp.productID]).
            get(),//occure error
              builder: (c,snap)
              {
                return snap.hasData?AdminOrderCard(
                  itemCount: snap.data.docs.length,
                  data:snap.data.docs,
                  orderId: snapshots.data.docs[index].id,
                  orderBy:snapshots.data.docs[index].data()["orderBy"],//occure error
                  addressID:snapshots.data.docs[index].data()
                  ["addressID"],//occure error
                )
                    :Center(child: circularProgress(),);
              },

            );
 List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getCategoriesDropdown(){
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = new List();
    for(int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){

      setState(() {
          print(i);
        items.insert(0, DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(categories[i].data()['category']),
            value: categories[i].data()['category']));
      });
    }
    return items;
  }
  

   _currentCategory = categories[0].data()['category'];  //The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (Documentation)
```

pro.dart:

```
Future<void> getMobileandTabIconData() async {
  List<CategoryIcon> newList = [];
  QuerySnapshot dressSnapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("categoryicon")
      .doc("MhZyArOf2zrOmPO7R3y6")
      .collection("mobile&tablets")
      .get();
  dressSnapShot.docs.forEach(
        (element) {
      mobileandtabiconData = CategoryIcon(image: element.data()["image"]);//error occure 
      newList.add(mobileandtabiconData);
    },
  );
  mobileandtabIcon = newList;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: can you show where categories come from?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hopefully, I covered all your errors.

```dart
Product.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
  Map<String, dynamic> json = snapshot.data();
  // FEATURED, BRAND AND CATEGORY SHOULD BE Strings
  _featured = json[FEATURED];
  _brand = json[BRAND];
  _category = json[CATEGORY];
}
...
Map<String, dynamic> data = data.docs[index].data();
// EcommerceApp.productID should be a string
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("items")
    .where("shortInfo", whereIn: snapshots.data[EcommerceApp.productID])
    .get();
...
Map<String, dynamic> data1 = snapshots.data.docs[index].data();
return snap.hasData?AdminOrderCard(
    itemCount: snap.data.docs.length,
    data:snap.data.docs,
    orderId: snapshots.data.docs[index].id,
    orderBy: data1["orderBy"],
    addressID: data1["addressID"],
  );
...
Map<String, dynamic> categoryDoc = categories[0].data();
_currentCategory = categoryDoc['category'];
...
Map<String, dynamic> imageDoc = element.data();
mobileandtabiconData = CategoryIcon(image: imageDoc["image"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `categories` variable is typed as a `List`.

Easiest (though a bit hacky) way to achieve this, is to change your line of code to the following.

```
 _currentCategory = (categories as List)[0].data()['category'];  //The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (Documentation)
```

Comment: What are the actual errors for each line?

Comment: Bro many line of code show same error above code i could not found solution yet?

Comment: Casting it like I showed above doesn't resolve the error for than line?

Comment: your casting is successfully solved category error but i have future builder function which is occure error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: error show in each line where i added  in last of line //error occure comment show error this [] operator is not defind for the type object

Comment: Change your occurances of data.docs to (data.docs as List)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the data which you get back from the API is in same data type as expected, that is what has worked for me.. like type casting it to (as List;)